# Find the minimum distance between points of three lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I've got three files containing tables of numbers, each with three columns and a different number of rows from file to file. The three columns represent coordinates of points on some three axes. I need to find the three points in the files that are the closest among themselves. This is what I've done so far: i simply compute the distance for each couple of points in the three files, and print those that are below a certain tolerance, but I'm not sure how to select the three that have the smallest distance between them.

```
PRCLMatrix = np.loadtxt("path.../PRCL_wp.txt")
MICHMatrix = np.loadtxt("path.../MICH_wp.txt")
SRCLMatrix = np.loadtxt("path.../SRCL_wp.txt")
tolerance = 0.11

for i in range(len(PRCLMatrix)):
    for j in range(len(MICHMatrix)):
        for k in range(len(SRCLMatrix)):
            disPRCLMICH = np.sqrt((PRCLMatrix[i,0]-MICHMatrix[j,0])**2 + (PRCLMatrix[i,1]-MICHMatrix[j,1])**2 + (PRCLMatrix[i,2]-MICHMatrix[j,2])**2)
            disPRCLSRCL = np.sqrt((PRCLMatrix[i,0]-SRCLMatrix[k,0])**2 + (PRCLMatrix[i,1]-SRCLMatrix[k,1])**2 + (PRCLMatrix[i,2]-SRCLMatrix[k,2])**2)
            disSRCLMICH = np.sqrt((SRCLMatrix[k,0]-MICHMatrix[j,0])**2 + (SRCLMatrix[k,1]-MICHMatrix[j,1])**2 + (SRCLMatrix[k,2]-MICHMatrix[j,2])**2)
            if disPRCLMICH < tolerance and disPRCLSRCL < tolerance and disSRCLMICH < tolerance:
                print(PRCLMatrix[i,:])
                print(MICHMatrix[j,:])
                print(SRCLMatrix[k,:])
                print("\n")
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by smallest distance between three points? Do you want the sum of the distances between each pair of points in the triplet to be minimized?

Comment: i want the distance between each couple to be the minimum. This might also be translated as minimizing the sum of their absolute values, i think.

Comment: Well since you already know what quantity to minimize, just keep track of that value and replace it if the new value is less than the previously calculated minimum value.

Comment: Also you don't need to write out the entire distance formula: `disPRCLMICH = np.linalg.norm(PRCLMatrix[i, :] - MICHMatrix[j, :])`